# Rendered Liquid template to Python dict

Tags: python, liquid

I have the following Liquid template:

```
{%- capture vars -%}  
{%- capture articleHeadline -%}This is the article of the headline{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- capture intro -%}

Introduction to the document

{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- capture articleHighlights -%}

Step 1: Get up

Step 2: Go to kitchen

Step 3: Get coffee

{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- capture articleSummary -%}

Summary of the document

{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- endcapture -%}
```

I'd like to parse this text and end up with a `dict` of the form:

```
{
    "articleHeadline": "This is the article of the headline",
    "intro": "\nIntroduction to the document\n"
    "articleHighlights": "\nStep 1: Get up\n\nStep 2: Go to kitchen\n\nStep 3: Get coffee\n",
    "articleSummary": "\nSummary of the document\n"
}
```

I tried [Python Liquid](https://jg-rp.github.io/liquid/) but I'm confident it does not reverse engineer templates like this. I also checked out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) for this purpose but it will only parse HTML tags.

Is there a library or method that I can use to parse this (hopefully avoiding regex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you that confident that Python Liquid doesn't do this? ;-)

I've never used the library before, but it seems to expose a parser API that returns the AST (abstract syntax tree) of the template; from there on out it's just a recursive function away to find all `capture` blocks and return their contents.

```
from pprint import pprint

from liquid.builtin.tags.capture_tag import CaptureNode
from liquid.environment import Environment

template = """
{%- capture vars -%}  
{%- capture articleHeadline -%}This is the article of the headline{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- capture intro -%}

Introduction to the document

{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- capture articleHighlights -%}

Step 1: Get up

Step 2: Go to kitchen

Step 3: Get coffee

{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- capture articleSummary -%}

Summary of the document

{%- endcapture -%}  
{%- endcapture -%}
"""


def get_capture_contents(node):
    if isinstance(node, CaptureNode):
        yield (node.name, node.block)
    if hasattr(node, "children"):
        for child in node.children():
            yield from get_capture_contents(child.node)


env = Environment()
ast = env.parse(template)
blocks = {}
for stmt in ast.statements:
    for cap_name, content in get_capture_contents(stmt):
        blocks[cap_name] = str(content)

pprint(blocks)
```

prints out

```
{'articleHeadline': 'This is the article of the headline',
 'articleHighlights': 'Step 1: Get up\n'
                      '\n'
                      'Step 2: Go to kitchen\n'
                      '\n'
                      'Step 3: Get coffee',
 'articleSummary': 'Summary of the document',
 'intro': 'Introduction to the document',
 'vars': 'var articleHeadline = { This is the article of the headline }var '
         'intro = { Introduction to the document }var articleHighlights = { '
         'Step 1: Get up\n'
         '\n'
         'Step 2: Go to kitchen\n'
         '\n'
         'Step 3: Get coffee }var articleSummary = { Summary of the document }'}
```

Comment: I got as far as exposing the Tree. I did not take the step to parse it properly. I guess I'm just a sh*tty programmer LOL - thank you